# How to break page result of Maple output?

Tags: page-breaking, maple2e

I have a file which Maple out put.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=20mm,right=20mm,top=15mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{maple2e}
 \def\emptyline{\vspace{12pt}}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Output}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Output}
\DefineCharStyle{2D Math}
\DefineCharStyle{2D Output}
\begin{document}
\begin{maplegroup}
\begin{maplelatex}
\maplemultiline{
[[1, \,-9, \,-1, \,10, \,1, \,[9, \,10]], \,[1, \,-8, \,-1, \,9, 
\,1, \,[8, \,9]], \,[1, \,-7, \,-1, \,8, \,1, \,[7, \,8]],  \\
[1, \,-6, \,-1, \,7, \,1, \,[6, \,7]], \,[1, \,-6, \,-1, \,10, \,
2, \,[6, \,10]], \,[1, \,-5, \,-1, \,6, \,1, \,[5, \,6]],  \\
[1, \,-5, \,-1, \,9, \,2, \,[5, \,9]], \,[1, \,-5, \,-1, \,10, \,
3, \,[6, \,9]], \,[1, \,-4, \,-1, \,5, \,1, \,[4, \,5]],  \\
[1, \,-4, \,-1, \,8, \,2, \,[4, \,8]], \,[1, \,-4, \,-1, \,9, \,3
, \,[5, \,8]], \,[1, \,-3, \,-1, \,4, \,1, \,[3, \,4]],  \\
[1, \,-3, \,-1, \,7, \,2, \,[3, \,7]], \,[1, \,-3, \,-1, \,8, \,3
, \,[4, \,7]], \,[1, \,-2, \,-3, \,10, \,2, \,[2, \,3]],  \\
[1, \,-2, \,-1, \,3, \,1, \,[2, \,3]], \,[1, \,-2, \,-1, \,6, \,2
, \,[2, \,6]], \,[1, \,-2, \,-1, \,7, \,3, \,[3, \,6]],  \\
[1, \,-1, \,-3, \,7, \,2, \,[1, \,2]], \,[1, \,-1, \,-1, \,2, \,1
, \,[1, \,2]], \,[1, \,-1, \,-1, \,5, \,2, \,[1, \,5]],  \\
[1, \,-1, \,-1, \,6, \,3, \,[2, \,5]], \,[1, \,-1, \,-1, \,10, \,
3, \,[1, \,10]], \,[1, \,1, \,-2, \,7, \,3, \,[-1, \,3]],  \\
[1, \,1, \,-1, \,3, \,2, \,[-1, \,3]], \,[1, \,1, \,-1, \,8, \,3
, \,[-1, \,8]], \,[1, \,2, \,-9, \,7, \,5, \,[-2, \,-1]],  \\
[1, \,2, \,-7, \,2, \,4, \,[-2, \,-1]], \,[1, \,2, \,-5, \,-1, \,
3, \,[-2, \,-1]], \,[1, \,2, \,-3, \,-2, \,2, \,[-2, \,-1]],  \\
[1, \,2, \,-3, \,10, \,4, \,[-2, \,2]], \,[1, \,2, \,-2, \,5, \,3
, \,[-2, \,2]], \,[1, \,2, \,-1, \,-1, \,1, \,[-2, \,-1]],  \\
[1, \,2, \,-1, \,2, \,2, \,[-2, \,2]], \,[1, \,2, \,-1, \,3, \,3
, \,[-1, \,2]], \,[1, \,2, \,-1, \,7, \,3, \,[-2, \,7]],  \\
[1, \,2, \,-1, \,8, \,4, \,[-1, \,7]], \,[1, \,3, \,-9, \,-2, \,5
, \,[-3, \,-2]], \,[1, \,3, \,-7, \,-5, \,4, \,[-3, \,-2]],  \\
[1, \,3, \,-5, \,-6, \,3, \,[-3, \,-2]], \,[1, \,3, \,-3, \,-5, 
\,2, \,[-3, \,-2]], \,[1, \,3, \,-3, \,7, \,4, \,[-3, \,1]],  \\
[1, \,3, \,-2, \,3, \,3, \,[-3, \,1]], \,[1, \,3, \,-1, \,-2, \,1
, \,[-3, \,-2]], \,[1, \,3, \,-1, \,1, \,2, \,[-3, \,1]],  \\
[1, \,3, \,-1, \,2, \,3, \,[-2, \,1]], \,[1, \,3, \,-1, \,6, \,3
, \,[-3, \,6]], \,[1, \,3, \,-1, \,7, \,4, \,[-2, \,6]],  \\
[1, \,3, \,-1, \,10, \,5, \,[1, \,6]], \,[1, \,4, \,-3, \,-8, \,2
, \,[-4, \,-3]], \,[1, \,4, \,-1, \,-3, \,1, \,[-4, \,-3]],  \\
[1, \,4, \,-1, \,5, \,3, \,[-4, \,5]], \,[1, \,4, \,-1, \,6, \,4
, \,[-3, \,5]], \,[1, \,5, \,-4, \,5, \,5, \,[-5, \,-1]],  \\
[1, \,5, \,-3, \,1, \,4, \,[-5, \,-1]], \,[1, \,5, \,-2, \,-1, \,
3, \,[-5, \,-1]], \,[1, \,5, \,-1, \,-4, \,1, \,[-5, \,-4]],  \\
[1, \,5, \,-1, \,-1, \,2, \,[-5, \,-1]], \,[1, \,5, \,-1, \,4, \,
3, \,[-5, \,4]], \,[1, \,5, \,-1, \,5, \,4, \,[-4, \,4]],  \\
[1, \,5, \,-1, \,8, \,5, \,[-1, \,4]], \,[1, \,6, \,-5, \,6, \,6
, \,[-6, \,-2]], \,[1, \,6, \,-4, \,1, \,5, \,[-6, \,-2]],  \\
[1, \,6, \,-3, \,-2, \,4, \,[-6, \,-2]], \,[1, \,6, \,-2, \,-3, 
\,3, \,[-6, \,-2]], \,[1, \,6, \,-1, \,-5, \,1, \,[-6, \,-5]], 
 \\
[1, \,6, \,-1, \,-2, \,2, \,[-6, \,-2]], \,[1, \,6, \,-1, \,-1, 
\,3, \,[-5, \,-2]], \,[1, \,6, \,-1, \,3, \,3, \,[-6, \,3]],  \\
[1, \,6, \,-1, \,4, \,4, \,[-5, \,3]], \,[1, \,6, \,-1, \,7, \,5
, \,[-2, \,3]], \,[1, \,6, \,-1, \,10, \,4, \,[-6, \,10]],  \\
[1, \,7, \,-6, \,7, \,7, \,[-7, \,-3]], \,[1, \,7, \,-5, \,1, \,6
, \,[-7, \,-3]], \,[1, \,7, \,-4, \,-3, \,5, \,[-7, \,-3]],  \\
[1, \,7, \,-3, \,-5, \,4, \,[-7, \,-3]], \,[1, \,7, \,-2, \,-5, 
\,3, \,[-7, \,-3]], \,[1, \,7, \,-1, \,-6, \,1, \,[-7, \,-6]], 
 \\
[1, \,7, \,-1, \,-3, \,2, \,[-7, \,-3]], \,[1, \,7, \,-1, \,-2, 
\,3, \,[-6, \,-3]], \,[1, \,7, \,-1, \,2, \,3, \,[-7, \,2]],  \\
[1, \,7, \,-1, \,3, \,4, \,[-6, \,2]], \,[1, \,7, \,-1, \,6, \,5
, \,[-3, \,2]], \,[1, \,7, \,-1, \,9, \,4, \,[-7, \,9]],  \\
[1, \,7, \,-1, \,10, \,5, \,[-6, \,9]], \,[1, \,8, \,-6, \,1, \,7
, \,[-8, \,-4]], \,[1, \,8, \,-5, \,-4, \,6, \,[-8, \,-4]],  \\
[1, \,8, \,-4, \,-7, \,5, \,[-8, \,-4]], \,[1, \,8, \,-3, \,-8, 
\,4, \,[-8, \,-4]], \,[1, \,8, \,-2, \,-7, \,3, \,[-8, \,-4]], 
 \\
[1, \,8, \,-1, \,-7, \,1, \,[-8, \,-7]], \,[1, \,8, \,-1, \,-4, 
\,2, \,[-8, \,-4]], \,[1, \,8, \,-1, \,-3, \,3, \,[-7, \,-4]], 
 \\
[1, \,8, \,-1, \,1, \,3, \,[-8, \,1]], \,[1, \,8, \,-1, \,2, \,4
, \,[-7, \,1]], \,[1, \,8, \,-1, \,5, \,5, \,[-4, \,1]],  \\
[1, \,8, \,-1, \,8, \,4, \,[-8, \,8]], \,[1, \,8, \,-1, \,9, \,5
, \,[-7, \,8]], \,[1, \,9, \,-6, \,-5, \,7, \,[-9, \,-5]],  \\
[1, \,9, \,-5, \,-9, \,6, \,[-9, \,-5]], \,[1, \,9, \,-2, \,-9, 
\,3, \,[-9, \,-5]], \,[1, \,9, \,-1, \,-8, \,1, \,[-9, \,-8]], 
 \\
[1, \,9, \,-1, \,-5, \,2, \,[-9, \,-5]], \,[1, \,9, \,-1, \,-4, 
\,3, \,[-8, \,-5]], \,[1, \,9, \,-1, \,7, \,4, \,[-9, \,7]],  \\
[1, \,9, \,-1, \,8, \,5, \,[-8, \,7]], \,[1, \,10, \,-9, \,10, \,
10, \,[-10, \,-6]], \,[1, \,10, \,-3, \,6, \,6, \,[-10, \,-1]], 
 \\
[1, \,10, \,-2, \,7, \,6, \,[-9, \,-1]], \,[1, \,10, \,-1, \,-9, 
\,1, \,[-10, \,-9]], \,[1, \,10, \,-1, \,-6, \,2, \,[-10, \,-6]]
,  \\
[1, \,10, \,-1, \,-5, \,3, \,[-9, \,-6]], \,[1, \,10, \,-1, \,-1
, \,3, \,[-10, \,-1]], \,[1, \,10, \,-1, \,3, \,5, \,[-6, \,-1]]
,  \\
[1, \,10, \,-1, \,6, \,4, \,[-10, \,6]], \,[1, \,10, \,-1, \,7, 
\,5, \,[-9, \,6]], \,[1, \,10, \,-1, \,10, \,6, \,[-6, \,6]], 
 \\
[2, \,-9, \,-1, \,9, \,3, \,[5, \,9]], \,[2, \,-7, \,-1, \,8, \,3
, \,[4, \,8]], \,[2, \,-6, \,-2, \,10, \,2, \,[3, \,5]],  \\
[2, \,-5, \,-1, \,7, \,3, \,[3, \,7]], \,[2, \,-4, \,-2, \,8, \,2
, \,[2, \,4]], \,[2, \,-3, \,-1, \,6, \,3, \,[2, \,6]],  \\
[2, \,-2, \,-2, \,6, \,2, \,[1, \,3]], \,[2, \,-1, \,-1, \,5, \,3
, \,[1, \,5]], \,[2, \,2, \,-6, \,10, \,4, \,[-1, \,1]],  \\
[2, \,2, \,-4, \,5, \,3, \,[-1, \,1]], \,[2, \,2, \,-2, \,2, \,2
, \,[-1, \,1]], \,[2, \,3, \,-2, \,7, \,4, \,[-1, \,3]],  \\
[2, \,3, \,-1, \,3, \,3, \,[-1, \,3]], \,[2, \,5, \,-3, \,10, \,5
, \,[-2, \,2]], \,[2, \,5, \,-2, \,5, \,4, \,[-2, \,2]],  \\
[2, \,5, \,-1, \,2, \,3, \,[-2, \,2]], \,[2, \,6, \,-10, \,6, \,6
, \,[-3, \,-1]], \,[2, \,6, \,-8, \,1, \,5, \,[-3, \,-1]],  \\
[2, \,6, \,-6, \,-2, \,4, \,[-3, \,-1]], \,[2, \,6, \,-4, \,-3, 
\,3, \,[-3, \,-1]], \,[2, \,6, \,-2, \,-2, \,2, \,[-3, \,-1]], 
 \\
[2, \,6, \,-2, \,10, \,4, \,[-3, \,5]], \,[2, \,7, \,-3, \,7, \,5
, \,[-3, \,1]], \,[2, \,7, \,-2, \,3, \,4, \,[-3, \,1]],  \\
[2, \,7, \,-1, \,1, \,3, \,[-3, \,1]], \,[2, \,7, \,-1, \,10, \,6
, \,[1, \,9]], \,[2, \,8, \,-10, \,-4, \,6, \,[-4, \,-2]],  \\
[2, \,8, \,-8, \,-7, \,5, \,[-4, \,-2]], \,[2, \,8, \,-6, \,-8, 
\,4, \,[-4, \,-2]], \,[2, \,8, \,-4, \,-7, \,3, \,[-4, \,-2]], 
 \\
[2, \,8, \,-2, \,-4, \,2, \,[-4, \,-2]], \,[2, \,8, \,-2, \,8, \,
4, \,[-4, \,4]], \,[2, \,10, \,-3, \,10, \,5, \,[-5, \,3]],  \\
[2, \,10, \,-2, \,-6, \,2, \,[-5, \,-3]], \,[2, \,10, \,-2, \,6, 
\,4, \,[-5, \,3]], \,[2, \,10, \,-2, \,10, \,6, \,[-3, \,3]], 
 \\
[3, \,-8, \,-1, \,4, \,2, \,[3, \,4]], \,[3, \,-8, \,-1, \,8, \,4
, \,[4, \,8]], \,[3, \,-5, \,-3, \,10, \,3, \,[2, \,3]],  \\
[3, \,-5, \,-1, \,3, \,2, \,[2, \,3]], \,[3, \,-5, \,-1, \,7, \,4
, \,[3, \,7]], \,[3, \,-2, \,-3, \,7, \,3, \,[1, \,2]],  \\
[3, \,-2, \,-1, \,2, \,2, \,[1, \,2]], \,[3, \,-2, \,-1, \,6, \,4
, \,[2, \,6]], \,[3, \,1, \,-1, \,5, \,4, \,[1, \,5]],  \\
[3, \,3, \,-3, \,6, \,3, \,[-1, \,2]], \,[3, \,6, \,-5, \,6, \,4
, \,[-2, \,1]], \,[3, \,6, \,-3, \,3, \,3, \,[-2, \,1]],  \\
[3, \,6, \,-1, \,10, \,6, \,[1, \,10]], \,[3, \,7, \,-9, \,7, \,6
, \,[-2, \,-1]], \,[3, \,7, \,-7, \,2, \,5, \,[-2, \,-1]],  \\
[3, \,7, \,-5, \,-1, \,4, \,[-2, \,-1]], \,[3, \,7, \,-3, \,-2, 
\,3, \,[-2, \,-1]], \,[3, \,7, \,-3, \,10, \,5, \,[-2, \,3]], 
 \\
[3, \,7, \,-2, \,7, \,5, \,[-1, \,3]], \,[3, \,7, \,-1, \,-1, \,2
, \,[-2, \,-1]], \,[3, \,7, \,-1, \,3, \,4, \,[-1, \,3]],  \\
[3, \,10, \,-9, \,-2, \,6, \,[-3, \,-2]], \,[3, \,10, \,-7, \,-5
, \,5, \,[-3, \,-2]], \,[3, \,10, \,-5, \,-6, \,4, \,[-3, \,-2]]
,  \\
[3, \,10, \,-3, \,-5, \,3, \,[-3, \,-2]], \,[3, \,10, \,-3, \,7, 
\,5, \,[-3, \,2]], \,[3, \,10, \,-3, \,10, \,6, \,[-2, \,2]], 
 \\
[3, \,10, \,-2, \,5, \,5, \,[-2, \,2]], \,[3, \,10, \,-2, \,10, 
\,5, \,[-3, \,5]], \,[3, \,10, \,-1, \,-2, \,2, \,[-3, \,-2]], 
 \\
[3, \,10, \,-1, \,2, \,4, \,[-2, \,2]], \,[4, \,-7, \,-2, \,8, \,
3, \,[2, \,4]], \,[4, \,-7, \,-1, \,8, \,5, \,[4, \,8]],  \\
[4, \,-4, \,-4, \,8, \,2, \,[1, \,2]], \,[4, \,-3, \,-2, \,6, \,3
, \,[1, \,3]], \,[4, \,-3, \,-1, \,7, \,5, \,[3, \,7]],  \\
[4, \,1, \,-1, \,6, \,5, \,[2, \,6]], \,[4, \,5, \,-6, \,10, \,5
, \,[-1, \,1]], \,[4, \,5, \,-4, \,5, \,4, \,[-1, \,1]],  \\
[4, \,5, \,-2, \,2, \,3, \,[-1, \,1]], \,[4, \,5, \,-1, \,5, \,5
, \,[1, \,5]], \,[4, \,8, \,-8, \,-7, \,3, \,[-2, \,-1]],  \\
[4, \,8, \,-4, \,-4, \,2, \,[-2, \,-1]], \,[4, \,8, \,-4, \,8, \,
4, \,[-2, \,2]], \,[5, \,-9, \,-1, \,9, \,6, \,[5, \,9]],  \\
[5, \,-6, \,-3, \,10, \,4, \,[2, \,3]], \,[5, \,-6, \,-1, \,3, \,
3, \,[2, \,3]], \,[5, \,-4, \,-1, \,8, \,6, \,[4, \,8]],  \\
[5, \,-1, \,-3, \,7, \,4, \,[1, \,2]], \,[5, \,-1, \,-1, \,2, \,3
, \,[1, \,2]], \,[5, \,1, \,-1, \,7, \,6, \,[3, \,7]],  \\
[5, \,6, \,-3, \,6, \,4, \,[-1, \,2]], \,[5, \,6, \,-1, \,6, \,6
, \,[2, \,6]], \,[6, \,-8, \,-2, \,8, \,4, \,[2, \,4]],  \\
[6, \,-5, \,-1, \,9, \,7, \,[5, \,9]], \,[6, \,-2, \,-2, \,6, \,4
, \,[1, \,3]], \,[6, \,1, \,-1, \,8, \,7, \,[4, \,8]],  \\
[6, \,7, \,-1, \,7, \,7, \,[3, \,7]], \,[6, \,10, \,-6, \,10, \,6
, \,[-1, \,1]], \,[6, \,10, \,-4, \,5, \,5, \,[-1, \,1]],  \\
[6, \,10, \,-2, \,2, \,4, \,[-1, \,1]], \,[7, \,-5, \,-3, \,10, 
\,5, \,[2, \,3]], \,[7, \,-5, \,-1, \,3, \,4, \,[2, \,3]],  \\
[7, \,2, \,-3, \,7, \,5, \,[1, \,2]], \,[7, \,2, \,-1, \,2, \,4, 
\,[1, \,2]], \,[8, \,-7, \,-4, \,8, \,3, \,[1, \,2]],  \\
[8, \,-7, \,-2, \,8, \,5, \,[2, \,4]], \,[8, \,1, \,-2, \,6, \,5
, \,[1, \,3]], \,[8, \,8, \,-8, \,8, \,4, \,[-1, \,1]],  \\
[9, \,-2, \,-3, \,10, \,6, \,[2, \,3]], \,[9, \,-2, \,-1, \,3, \,
5, \,[2, \,3]], \,[9, \,7, \,-3, \,7, \,6, \,[1, \,2]],  \\
[9, \,7, \,-1, \,2, \,5, \,[1, \,2]], \,[9, \,10, \,-1, \,10, \,
10, \,[6, \,10]], \,[10, \,-4, \,-2, \,8, \,6, \,[2, \,4]],  \\
\,5, \,[2, \,3]], \,[7, \,-5, \,-1, \,3, \,4, \,[2, \,3]],  \\
[7, \,2, \,-3, \,7, \,5, \,[1, \,2]], \,[7, \,2, \,-1, \,2, \,4, 
\,[1, \,2]], \,[8, \,-7, \,-4, \,8, \,3, \,[1, \,2]],  \\
[8, \,-7, \,-2, \,8, \,5, \,[2, \,4]], \,[8, \,1, \,-2, \,6, \,5
, \,[1, \,3]], \,[8, \,8, \,-8, \,8, \,4, \,[-1, \,1]],  \\
[9, \,-2, \,-3, \,10, \,6, \,[2, \,3]], \,[9, \,-2, \,-1, \,3, \,
5, \,[2, \,3]], \,[9, \,7, \,-3, \,7, \,6, \,[1, \,2]],  \\
[9, \,7, \,-1, \,2, \,5, \,[1, \,2]], \,[9, \,10, \,-1, \,10, \,
10, \,[6, \,10]], \,[10, \,-4, \,-2, \,8, \,6, \,[2, \,4]],  \\
[10, \,6, \,-2, \,6, \,6, \,[1, \,3]]] }
\end{maplelatex}
\end{maplegroup}

\end{document}
```

The result can not break page. How to break page this file?

Comment: The `maple2e` package is not on CTAN, can you provide a link?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/wine/dosdevices/z:/mit/foley/sty/maple2e.sty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `maplelatex` and `maplemultiline` put their contents in unbreakable vboxes.  The former is changed by altering the definition of `\endmaplelatex`, replacing a `\centerline` by group containing a `\centering` command.  The latter is changed by adjusting the definition of `\@dumplinebuffer`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=20mm,right=20mm,top=15mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{maple2e}
 \def\emptyline{\vspace{12pt}}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Output}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Output}
\DefineCharStyle{2D Math}
\DefineCharStyle{2D Output}

\makeatletter
\def\@dumplinebuffer{%
\hbox{\vrule height3pt depth0pt width 0pt}%
\unvbox\@linebuffer
\global\setbox\@linebuffer=\vbox{}%
\relax}

\def\endmaplelatex{\egroup%
\edef\@MapleIOType{\MapleIOType}%
\ifx\@MapleIOType\@MapleQuiet% 
\par%
\else%
\nopagebreak[3]%
\bgroup\centering%
\hbox{\vrule height4pt depth0pt width 0pt}%
\unvbox\maplebox\par\egroup
\vskip\BelowMapleSkip%
\everypar{}%
\par%
\fi%
}%


\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{maplegroup}
\begin{maplelatex}
\maplemultiline{
[[1, \,-9, \,-1, \,10, \,1, \,[9, \,10]], \,[1, \,-8, \,-1, \,9, 
\,1, \,[8, \,9]], \,[1, \,-7, \,-1, \,8, \,1, \,[7, \,8]],  \\
[1, \,-6, \,-1, \,7, \,1, \,[6, \,7]], \,[1, \,-6, \,-1, \,10, \,
2, \,[6, \,10]], \,[1, \,-5, \,-1, \,6, \,1, \,[5, \,6]],  \\
[1, \,-5, \,-1, \,9, \,2, \,[5, \,9]], \,[1, \,-5, \,-1, \,10, \,
3, \,[6, \,9]], \,[1, \,-4, \,-1, \,5, \,1, \,[4, \,5]],  \\
[1, \,-4, \,-1, \,8, \,2, \,[4, \,8]], \,[1, \,-4, \,-1, \,9, \,3
, \,[5, \,8]], \,[1, \,-3, \,-1, \,4, \,1, \,[3, \,4]],  \\
[1, \,-3, \,-1, \,7, \,2, \,[3, \,7]], \,[1, \,-3, \,-1, \,8, \,3
, \,[4, \,7]], \,[1, \,-2, \,-3, \,10, \,2, \,[2, \,3]],  \\
[1, \,-2, \,-1, \,3, \,1, \,[2, \,3]], \,[1, \,-2, \,-1, \,6, \,2
, \,[2, \,6]], \,[1, \,-2, \,-1, \,7, \,3, \,[3, \,6]],  \\
[1, \,-1, \,-3, \,7, \,2, \,[1, \,2]], \,[1, \,-1, \,-1, \,2, \,1
, \,[1, \,2]], \,[1, \,-1, \,-1, \,5, \,2, \,[1, \,5]],  \\
[1, \,-1, \,-1, \,6, \,3, \,[2, \,5]], \,[1, \,-1, \,-1, \,10, \,
3, \,[1, \,10]], \,[1, \,1, \,-2, \,7, \,3, \,[-1, \,3]],  \\
[1, \,1, \,-1, \,3, \,2, \,[-1, \,3]], \,[1, \,1, \,-1, \,8, \,3
, \,[-1, \,8]], \,[1, \,2, \,-9, \,7, \,5, \,[-2, \,-1]],  \\
[1, \,2, \,-7, \,2, \,4, \,[-2, \,-1]], \,[1, \,2, \,-5, \,-1, \,
3, \,[-2, \,-1]], \,[1, \,2, \,-3, \,-2, \,2, \,[-2, \,-1]],  \\
[1, \,2, \,-3, \,10, \,4, \,[-2, \,2]], \,[1, \,2, \,-2, \,5, \,3
, \,[-2, \,2]], \,[1, \,2, \,-1, \,-1, \,1, \,[-2, \,-1]],  \\
[1, \,2, \,-1, \,2, \,2, \,[-2, \,2]], \,[1, \,2, \,-1, \,3, \,3
, \,[-1, \,2]], \,[1, \,2, \,-1, \,7, \,3, \,[-2, \,7]],  \\
[1, \,2, \,-1, \,8, \,4, \,[-1, \,7]], \,[1, \,3, \,-9, \,-2, \,5
, \,[-3, \,-2]], \,[1, \,3, \,-7, \,-5, \,4, \,[-3, \,-2]],  \\
[1, \,3, \,-5, \,-6, \,3, \,[-3, \,-2]], \,[1, \,3, \,-3, \,-5, 
\,2, \,[-3, \,-2]], \,[1, \,3, \,-3, \,7, \,4, \,[-3, \,1]],  \\
[1, \,3, \,-2, \,3, \,3, \,[-3, \,1]], \,[1, \,3, \,-1, \,-2, \,1
, \,[-3, \,-2]], \,[1, \,3, \,-1, \,1, \,2, \,[-3, \,1]],  \\
[1, \,3, \,-1, \,2, \,3, \,[-2, \,1]], \,[1, \,3, \,-1, \,6, \,3
, \,[-3, \,6]], \,[1, \,3, \,-1, \,7, \,4, \,[-2, \,6]],  \\
[1, \,3, \,-1, \,10, \,5, \,[1, \,6]], \,[1, \,4, \,-3, \,-8, \,2
, \,[-4, \,-3]], \,[1, \,4, \,-1, \,-3, \,1, \,[-4, \,-3]],  \\
[1, \,4, \,-1, \,5, \,3, \,[-4, \,5]], \,[1, \,4, \,-1, \,6, \,4
, \,[-3, \,5]], \,[1, \,5, \,-4, \,5, \,5, \,[-5, \,-1]],  \\
[1, \,5, \,-3, \,1, \,4, \,[-5, \,-1]], \,[1, \,5, \,-2, \,-1, \,
3, \,[-5, \,-1]], \,[1, \,5, \,-1, \,-4, \,1, \,[-5, \,-4]],  \\
[1, \,5, \,-1, \,-1, \,2, \,[-5, \,-1]], \,[1, \,5, \,-1, \,4, \,
3, \,[-5, \,4]], \,[1, \,5, \,-1, \,5, \,4, \,[-4, \,4]],  \\
[1, \,5, \,-1, \,8, \,5, \,[-1, \,4]], \,[1, \,6, \,-5, \,6, \,6
, \,[-6, \,-2]], \,[1, \,6, \,-4, \,1, \,5, \,[-6, \,-2]],  \\
[1, \,6, \,-3, \,-2, \,4, \,[-6, \,-2]], \,[1, \,6, \,-2, \,-3, 
\,3, \,[-6, \,-2]], \,[1, \,6, \,-1, \,-5, \,1, \,[-6, \,-5]], 
 \\
[1, \,6, \,-1, \,-2, \,2, \,[-6, \,-2]], \,[1, \,6, \,-1, \,-1, 
\,3, \,[-5, \,-2]], \,[1, \,6, \,-1, \,3, \,3, \,[-6, \,3]],  \\
[1, \,6, \,-1, \,4, \,4, \,[-5, \,3]], \,[1, \,6, \,-1, \,7, \,5
, \,[-2, \,3]], \,[1, \,6, \,-1, \,10, \,4, \,[-6, \,10]],  \\
[1, \,7, \,-6, \,7, \,7, \,[-7, \,-3]], \,[1, \,7, \,-5, \,1, \,6
, \,[-7, \,-3]], \,[1, \,7, \,-4, \,-3, \,5, \,[-7, \,-3]],  \\
[1, \,7, \,-3, \,-5, \,4, \,[-7, \,-3]], \,[1, \,7, \,-2, \,-5, 
\,3, \,[-7, \,-3]], \,[1, \,7, \,-1, \,-6, \,1, \,[-7, \,-6]], 
 \\
[1, \,7, \,-1, \,-3, \,2, \,[-7, \,-3]], \,[1, \,7, \,-1, \,-2, 
\,3, \,[-6, \,-3]], \,[1, \,7, \,-1, \,2, \,3, \,[-7, \,2]],  \\
[1, \,7, \,-1, \,3, \,4, \,[-6, \,2]], \,[1, \,7, \,-1, \,6, \,5
, \,[-3, \,2]], \,[1, \,7, \,-1, \,9, \,4, \,[-7, \,9]],  \\
[1, \,7, \,-1, \,10, \,5, \,[-6, \,9]], \,[1, \,8, \,-6, \,1, \,7
, \,[-8, \,-4]], \,[1, \,8, \,-5, \,-4, \,6, \,[-8, \,-4]],  \\
[1, \,8, \,-4, \,-7, \,5, \,[-8, \,-4]], \,[1, \,8, \,-3, \,-8, 
\,4, \,[-8, \,-4]], \,[1, \,8, \,-2, \,-7, \,3, \,[-8, \,-4]], 
 \\
[1, \,8, \,-1, \,-7, \,1, \,[-8, \,-7]], \,[1, \,8, \,-1, \,-4, 
\,2, \,[-8, \,-4]], \,[1, \,8, \,-1, \,-3, \,3, \,[-7, \,-4]], 
 \\
[1, \,8, \,-1, \,1, \,3, \,[-8, \,1]], \,[1, \,8, \,-1, \,2, \,4
, \,[-7, \,1]], \,[1, \,8, \,-1, \,5, \,5, \,[-4, \,1]],  \\
[1, \,8, \,-1, \,8, \,4, \,[-8, \,8]], \,[1, \,8, \,-1, \,9, \,5
, \,[-7, \,8]], \,[1, \,9, \,-6, \,-5, \,7, \,[-9, \,-5]],  \\
[1, \,9, \,-5, \,-9, \,6, \,[-9, \,-5]], \,[1, \,9, \,-2, \,-9, 
\,3, \,[-9, \,-5]], \,[1, \,9, \,-1, \,-8, \,1, \,[-9, \,-8]], 
 \\
[1, \,9, \,-1, \,-5, \,2, \,[-9, \,-5]], \,[1, \,9, \,-1, \,-4, 
\,3, \,[-8, \,-5]], \,[1, \,9, \,-1, \,7, \,4, \,[-9, \,7]],  \\
[1, \,9, \,-1, \,8, \,5, \,[-8, \,7]], \,[1, \,10, \,-9, \,10, \,
10, \,[-10, \,-6]], \,[1, \,10, \,-3, \,6, \,6, \,[-10, \,-1]], 
 \\
[1, \,10, \,-2, \,7, \,6, \,[-9, \,-1]], \,[1, \,10, \,-1, \,-9, 
\,1, \,[-10, \,-9]], \,[1, \,10, \,-1, \,-6, \,2, \,[-10, \,-6]]
,  \\
[1, \,10, \,-1, \,-5, \,3, \,[-9, \,-6]], \,[1, \,10, \,-1, \,-1
, \,3, \,[-10, \,-1]], \,[1, \,10, \,-1, \,3, \,5, \,[-6, \,-1]]
,  \\
[1, \,10, \,-1, \,6, \,4, \,[-10, \,6]], \,[1, \,10, \,-1, \,7, 
\,5, \,[-9, \,6]], \,[1, \,10, \,-1, \,10, \,6, \,[-6, \,6]], 
 \\
[2, \,-9, \,-1, \,9, \,3, \,[5, \,9]], \,[2, \,-7, \,-1, \,8, \,3
, \,[4, \,8]], \,[2, \,-6, \,-2, \,10, \,2, \,[3, \,5]],  \\
[2, \,-5, \,-1, \,7, \,3, \,[3, \,7]], \,[2, \,-4, \,-2, \,8, \,2
, \,[2, \,4]], \,[2, \,-3, \,-1, \,6, \,3, \,[2, \,6]],  \\
[2, \,-2, \,-2, \,6, \,2, \,[1, \,3]], \,[2, \,-1, \,-1, \,5, \,3
, \,[1, \,5]], \,[2, \,2, \,-6, \,10, \,4, \,[-1, \,1]],  \\
[2, \,2, \,-4, \,5, \,3, \,[-1, \,1]], \,[2, \,2, \,-2, \,2, \,2
, \,[-1, \,1]], \,[2, \,3, \,-2, \,7, \,4, \,[-1, \,3]],  \\
[2, \,3, \,-1, \,3, \,3, \,[-1, \,3]], \,[2, \,5, \,-3, \,10, \,5
, \,[-2, \,2]], \,[2, \,5, \,-2, \,5, \,4, \,[-2, \,2]],  \\
[2, \,5, \,-1, \,2, \,3, \,[-2, \,2]], \,[2, \,6, \,-10, \,6, \,6
, \,[-3, \,-1]], \,[2, \,6, \,-8, \,1, \,5, \,[-3, \,-1]],  \\
[2, \,6, \,-6, \,-2, \,4, \,[-3, \,-1]], \,[2, \,6, \,-4, \,-3, 
\,3, \,[-3, \,-1]], \,[2, \,6, \,-2, \,-2, \,2, \,[-3, \,-1]], 
 \\
[2, \,6, \,-2, \,10, \,4, \,[-3, \,5]], \,[2, \,7, \,-3, \,7, \,5
, \,[-3, \,1]], \,[2, \,7, \,-2, \,3, \,4, \,[-3, \,1]],  \\
[2, \,7, \,-1, \,1, \,3, \,[-3, \,1]], \,[2, \,7, \,-1, \,10, \,6
, \,[1, \,9]], \,[2, \,8, \,-10, \,-4, \,6, \,[-4, \,-2]],  \\
[2, \,8, \,-8, \,-7, \,5, \,[-4, \,-2]], \,[2, \,8, \,-6, \,-8, 
\,4, \,[-4, \,-2]], \,[2, \,8, \,-4, \,-7, \,3, \,[-4, \,-2]], 
 \\
[2, \,8, \,-2, \,-4, \,2, \,[-4, \,-2]], \,[2, \,8, \,-2, \,8, \,
4, \,[-4, \,4]], \,[2, \,10, \,-3, \,10, \,5, \,[-5, \,3]],  \\
[2, \,10, \,-2, \,-6, \,2, \,[-5, \,-3]], \,[2, \,10, \,-2, \,6, 
\,4, \,[-5, \,3]], \,[2, \,10, \,-2, \,10, \,6, \,[-3, \,3]], 
 \\
[3, \,-8, \,-1, \,4, \,2, \,[3, \,4]], \,[3, \,-8, \,-1, \,8, \,4
, \,[4, \,8]], \,[3, \,-5, \,-3, \,10, \,3, \,[2, \,3]],  \\
[3, \,-5, \,-1, \,3, \,2, \,[2, \,3]], \,[3, \,-5, \,-1, \,7, \,4
, \,[3, \,7]], \,[3, \,-2, \,-3, \,7, \,3, \,[1, \,2]],  \\
[3, \,-2, \,-1, \,2, \,2, \,[1, \,2]], \,[3, \,-2, \,-1, \,6, \,4
, \,[2, \,6]], \,[3, \,1, \,-1, \,5, \,4, \,[1, \,5]],  \\
[3, \,3, \,-3, \,6, \,3, \,[-1, \,2]], \,[3, \,6, \,-5, \,6, \,4
, \,[-2, \,1]], \,[3, \,6, \,-3, \,3, \,3, \,[-2, \,1]],  \\
[3, \,6, \,-1, \,10, \,6, \,[1, \,10]], \,[3, \,7, \,-9, \,7, \,6
, \,[-2, \,-1]], \,[3, \,7, \,-7, \,2, \,5, \,[-2, \,-1]],  \\
[3, \,7, \,-5, \,-1, \,4, \,[-2, \,-1]], \,[3, \,7, \,-3, \,-2, 
\,3, \,[-2, \,-1]], \,[3, \,7, \,-3, \,10, \,5, \,[-2, \,3]], 
 \\
[3, \,7, \,-2, \,7, \,5, \,[-1, \,3]], \,[3, \,7, \,-1, \,-1, \,2
, \,[-2, \,-1]], \,[3, \,7, \,-1, \,3, \,4, \,[-1, \,3]],  \\
[3, \,10, \,-9, \,-2, \,6, \,[-3, \,-2]], \,[3, \,10, \,-7, \,-5
, \,5, \,[-3, \,-2]], \,[3, \,10, \,-5, \,-6, \,4, \,[-3, \,-2]]
,  \\
[3, \,10, \,-3, \,-5, \,3, \,[-3, \,-2]], \,[3, \,10, \,-3, \,7, 
\,5, \,[-3, \,2]], \,[3, \,10, \,-3, \,10, \,6, \,[-2, \,2]], 
 \\
[3, \,10, \,-2, \,5, \,5, \,[-2, \,2]], \,[3, \,10, \,-2, \,10, 
\,5, \,[-3, \,5]], \,[3, \,10, \,-1, \,-2, \,2, \,[-3, \,-2]], 
 \\
[3, \,10, \,-1, \,2, \,4, \,[-2, \,2]], \,[4, \,-7, \,-2, \,8, \,
3, \,[2, \,4]], \,[4, \,-7, \,-1, \,8, \,5, \,[4, \,8]],  \\
[4, \,-4, \,-4, \,8, \,2, \,[1, \,2]], \,[4, \,-3, \,-2, \,6, \,3
, \,[1, \,3]], \,[4, \,-3, \,-1, \,7, \,5, \,[3, \,7]],  \\
[4, \,1, \,-1, \,6, \,5, \,[2, \,6]], \,[4, \,5, \,-6, \,10, \,5
, \,[-1, \,1]], \,[4, \,5, \,-4, \,5, \,4, \,[-1, \,1]],  \\
[4, \,5, \,-2, \,2, \,3, \,[-1, \,1]], \,[4, \,5, \,-1, \,5, \,5
, \,[1, \,5]], \,[4, \,8, \,-8, \,-7, \,3, \,[-2, \,-1]],  \\
[4, \,8, \,-4, \,-4, \,2, \,[-2, \,-1]], \,[4, \,8, \,-4, \,8, \,
4, \,[-2, \,2]], \,[5, \,-9, \,-1, \,9, \,6, \,[5, \,9]],  \\
[5, \,-6, \,-3, \,10, \,4, \,[2, \,3]], \,[5, \,-6, \,-1, \,3, \,
3, \,[2, \,3]], \,[5, \,-4, \,-1, \,8, \,6, \,[4, \,8]],  \\
[5, \,-1, \,-3, \,7, \,4, \,[1, \,2]], \,[5, \,-1, \,-1, \,2, \,3
, \,[1, \,2]], \,[5, \,1, \,-1, \,7, \,6, \,[3, \,7]],  \\
[5, \,6, \,-3, \,6, \,4, \,[-1, \,2]], \,[5, \,6, \,-1, \,6, \,6
, \,[2, \,6]], \,[6, \,-8, \,-2, \,8, \,4, \,[2, \,4]],  \\
[6, \,-5, \,-1, \,9, \,7, \,[5, \,9]], \,[6, \,-2, \,-2, \,6, \,4
, \,[1, \,3]], \,[6, \,1, \,-1, \,8, \,7, \,[4, \,8]],  \\
[6, \,7, \,-1, \,7, \,7, \,[3, \,7]], \,[6, \,10, \,-6, \,10, \,6
, \,[-1, \,1]], \,[6, \,10, \,-4, \,5, \,5, \,[-1, \,1]],  \\
[6, \,10, \,-2, \,2, \,4, \,[-1, \,1]], \,[7, \,-5, \,-3, \,10, 
\,5, \,[2, \,3]], \,[7, \,-5, \,-1, \,3, \,4, \,[2, \,3]],  \\
[7, \,2, \,-3, \,7, \,5, \,[1, \,2]], \,[7, \,2, \,-1, \,2, \,4, 
\,[1, \,2]], \,[8, \,-7, \,-4, \,8, \,3, \,[1, \,2]],  \\
[8, \,-7, \,-2, \,8, \,5, \,[2, \,4]], \,[8, \,1, \,-2, \,6, \,5
, \,[1, \,3]], \,[8, \,8, \,-8, \,8, \,4, \,[-1, \,1]],  \\
[9, \,-2, \,-3, \,10, \,6, \,[2, \,3]], \,[9, \,-2, \,-1, \,3, \,
5, \,[2, \,3]], \,[9, \,7, \,-3, \,7, \,6, \,[1, \,2]],  \\
[9, \,7, \,-1, \,2, \,5, \,[1, \,2]], \,[9, \,10, \,-1, \,10, \,
10, \,[6, \,10]], \,[10, \,-4, \,-2, \,8, \,6, \,[2, \,4]],  \\
\,5, \,[2, \,3]], \,[7, \,-5, \,-1, \,3, \,4, \,[2, \,3]],  \\
[7, \,2, \,-3, \,7, \,5, \,[1, \,2]], \,[7, \,2, \,-1, \,2, \,4, 
\,[1, \,2]], \,[8, \,-7, \,-4, \,8, \,3, \,[1, \,2]],  \\
[8, \,-7, \,-2, \,8, \,5, \,[2, \,4]], \,[8, \,1, \,-2, \,6, \,5
, \,[1, \,3]], \,[8, \,8, \,-8, \,8, \,4, \,[-1, \,1]],  \\
[9, \,-2, \,-3, \,10, \,6, \,[2, \,3]], \,[9, \,-2, \,-1, \,3, \,
5, \,[2, \,3]], \,[9, \,7, \,-3, \,7, \,6, \,[1, \,2]],  \\
[9, \,7, \,-1, \,2, \,5, \,[1, \,2]], \,[9, \,10, \,-1, \,10, \,
10, \,[6, \,10]], \,[10, \,-4, \,-2, \,8, \,6, \,[2, \,4]],  \\
[10, \,6, \,-2, \,6, \,6, \,[1, \,3]]] }
\end{maplelatex}
\end{maplegroup}

\end{document}
```